# Dotted underline TEXT

Tags: css, text, underline, dotted-line

I have a element (e.g. a label) with a fixed width and  I want that only the text to be dotted-underlined. If a do the "trick" with border-bottom the whole box will be underlined

I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mrg9a/) explains my problem

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap it into a span and add that border-bottom style to that span: http://jsfiddle.net/mrg9a/2/

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the text in `<span>` tags and then apply the style to the spans.

See the second element in this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mrg9a/3/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Since `label` elements are inline by default, the problem is caused by making them inline blocks. This in turn is presumably an attempt to avoid using the most natural and most effective way of structuring a form, namely an HTML table. Just switch to `table` markup and use `label` inside `td` with no fancy settings, and the `label` elements will take the border you set on them, in their natural width.